# Using the same dictionary as an argument for various functions, some have fewer arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, arguments

I have several functions that all take a whole bunch of the same arguments. Some of them have extra arguments on top of those. I'd like to pass the same dictionary into them all, but the ones with fewer arguments will complain about the extra items into the dictionary.

What is the best solution? Put useless dummy parameters into the functions with fewer arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make simple decorator that will use `inspect` module to get list of function parameters. This will give you example:

```
import inspect

def take_many_arguments(fn):
    origf = fn
    def _f(*arg, **args):
        new_args = {}

        for a in inspect.getargspec(origf).args:
            if a not in args:
                continue
            new_args[a] = args[a]

        return origf(*arg, **new_args)
    return _f


class C:
    @take_many_arguments
    def fn1(self, a):
        print(a)

    @take_many_arguments
    def fn2(self, a, b):
        print(a, b)

    @take_many_arguments
    def fn3(self, a, b, c):
        print(a, b, c)


@take_many_arguments
def fn4(a, b):
    print(a, b)


d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# for classes:
c = C()
c.fn1('Normal call')
c.fn1(**d)
c.fn2(**d)
c.fn3(**d)

# for functions:
fn4(9, 8)
fn4(**d)
```

Output:

```
Normal call
1
1 2
1 2 3
9 8
1 2
```

Comment: I like this a lot. One problem, though, is that it doesn't allow for any positional arguments to be passed into the decorated function, because `args[a]` will fail for that parameter (that parameter is inside `arg`). So for instance if I want to use this inside a class, I'm going to have trouble with the `self` parameter. The only way I thought of to avoid this was to add `if not a == 'self'` in between the `for a` line and the `new_args[a] = ` line. Is that how you'd handle it?

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, now the code in answer should work even for classes. I changed the example in the answer as well.